# ¿Cómo mejorar performance de un geom_histogram()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Me encuentro graficando un histograma a partir de un conjunto muy importante de datos mediante `geom_histogram()`, me he dado cuenta que a medida que se aumenta la "definición" del mismo aumentando en numero de `bins` o barras, el resultado es cada vez es más lento.  La relación, con un histograma de R base es de al menos 10 a 1 en tiempo. Ejemplo:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("microbenchmark")
set.seed(2019)
x <- rnorm(100000)
df <- data.frame(x=x)

ggplot_hist <- function(data, bins=100000){
  print(ggplot(data, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(bins=bins))
}

base_hist <- function(x, breaks=100000){
  print(hist(x, breaks=length(x)))
}

microbenchmark(
  base_hist(x), 
  ggplot_hist(df), 
  times=3L 
)

Unit: seconds
            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
    base_hist(x)  4.503556  4.632358  4.680143  4.761159  4.768436 4.775713     3
 ggplot_hist(df) 56.330033 57.249490 60.182923 58.168946 62.109369 66.049791    3
```

**¿Hay forma de optimizar un histograma en ggplot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la hipótesis [de esta interesante respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56614649/6836377), el cuello de botella estaría en el calculo de los `bins` o barras. Podemos intentar probarlo:

```
microbenchmark(
  ggplot_hist(df, bins=1), 
  ggplot_hist(df, bins=100), 
  ggplot_hist(df, bins=1000), 
  ggplot_hist(df, bins=10000), 
  ggplot_hist(df, bins=100000), 
  times=3
) -> tiempos
summary(tiempos)[, c(1,4), drop=FALSE]

                           expr       mean
1     ggplot_hist(df, bins = 1)   502.0619
2   ggplot_hist(df, bins = 100)   705.1292
3  ggplot_hist(df, bins = 1000)  1209.0673
4 ggplot_hist(df, bins = 10000)  6143.7755
5 ggplot_hist(df, bins = 1e+05) 55068.0312
```

Podemos observar, que a medida que incorporamos más nivel de detalle aumentando los `bins` el tiempo crece rápidamente. Por otro lado, si estudiamos el histograma "base" así:

```
microbenchmark(
  base_hist(df$x, breaks=1), 
  base_hist(df$x, breaks=100), 
  base_hist(df$x, breaks=1000), 
  base_hist(df$x, breaks=10000), 
  base_hist(df$x, breaks=100000), 
  times=3
) -> tiempos_base

summary(tiempos_base)[, c(1,4), drop=FALSE]
                             expr     mean
1     base_hist(df$x, breaks = 1) 10.49051
2   base_hist(df$x, breaks = 100) 10.46801
3  base_hist(df$x, breaks = 1000) 13.60592
4 base_hist(df$x, breaks = 10000) 16.48910
5 base_hist(df$x, breaks = 1e+05) 13.49401
```

Con el histograma básico, vemos que el crecimiento en el tiempo a medida que aumentan los `bins` es mínimo. Por lo que la idea, que se propone en la respuesta mencionada, es reemplazar el calculo de los `bins` con la función base `hist()` y dibujar luego las barras mediante un `geom_rect()`. Veamos:

```
quick_hist = function(x, bins=100000) {

  res = hist(x, plot=FALSE, breaks=bins)
  dat = data.frame(xmin=head(res$breaks, -1L),
                   xmax=tail(res$breaks, -1L),
                   ymin=0.0,
                   ymax=res$counts)

  print(ggplot(dat, aes(xmin=xmin, xmax=xmax, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax)) +
    geom_rect(size=0.5))
}

print(microbenchmark(
  base_hist(x), 
  ggplot_hist(df), 
  quick_hist(df$x), 
  times=3L 
), signif=3)

Unit: seconds
             expr   min    lq  mean median    uq  max neval
     base_hist(x)  4.75  4.76  7.70   4.76  9.17 13.6     3
  ggplot_hist(df) 57.30 57.40 57.60  57.40 57.80 58.1     3
 quick_hist(df$x)  6.45  6.64  9.57   6.83 11.10 15.4     3
```

Y vemos que con la función ad-hoc `quick_hist()`hemos logrado usando `ggplot` mejorar la performance del histograma de una forma radical y con un resultado visual muy similar.